# What happened to Saruman after he "died"?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

Gandalf the Gray was upgraded to Gandalf the White and  stepped in to fulfill Saruman's duties after he was "killed." What happened to Saruman of Many Colors? Did he remain dead even though he was a Maia, albeit a corrupted one, with the same origins and abilities as Gandalf?

Comment: Posted from my phone. Hope it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well this is what happened to him after he died:

> …about the body of Saruman a grey mist gathered, and rising slowly to a great height like smoke from a fire, as a pale shrouded figure it loomed over the Hill. For a moment it wavered, looking to the West; but out of the West came a cold wind, and it bent away, and with a cold sigh dissolved into nothing […] long years of death were suddenly revealed in [the body], and it shrank, and the shriveled face became rags of skin upon a hideous skull.
>
> *[The Return of the King]*

Sauron's death was similar to Saruman's and Gandalf states that Sauron was just going to wander around in Middle Earth, basically forever, as a power-less spirit, so you could assume the same happened to Saruman.

I got that quote from another question that basically answers yours, so I think that counts as duplicate but I'm not 100% sure.